# Check for missing json columns using pyspark

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I am working on following Customer Schema, my task is to process files let say 1000 every night, collect data from all input files into dataframe by cache them, and in the end made one database hive entry.
Issue is that during reading them in few cases **"InvoiceData"** is missing, I still need to process them by adding missing **"InvoiceData"** array 
with missing null values to look at them later, and do not break the process.
In dataframe I am just getting CompanyID, StoreID,StartTime, EndTime and  **"StoreData"**.

I need to create two dataframes once with CompanyID, StoreID,StartTime, EndTime **"InvoiceData"** array, 
Other with CompanyID, StoreID,StartTime, EndTime and  **"StoreData"**.

Since **"InvoiceData"** array is missing it is failing while readying data, how should I handle this case.

Code is in python 2.7

```
''' Current Customer Schema '''
root
 |-- CompanyID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- StoreID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- EndTime: double (nullable = true)
 |-- InvoiceData: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- TimeStamp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- productID: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- productName: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- productSKU: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- productUPC: double (nullable = true)
 |-- StoreData: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- TimeStamp: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- x: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- y: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- z: double (nullable = true)
 |-- StartTime: double (nullable = true)
```

Here is my current pyspark code

```
#!/bin/python2
import os
import subprocess
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import json
import sys

spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
        .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

def fn_customer(customer_data):
   df_customer = dict()
   df_customer = customer_data.select               \
           ( (col("Company_ID").alias("company_id"))   \
           , (col("StoreID").alias("Store_id"))        \
           , (col("StartTime").alias("start_time"))    \
           , (col("EndTime").alias("end_time"))        \
           , (explode(col("InvoiceData"))              \
                .alias("InvoiceData_ROW"))             \
           )
   df_customer.show(1)
   print ("Unexpexted Error df_customer : ", sys.exc_info()[0])

   print("Create df_customer  :")
   df_customer_invoice = customer_data.select  \
        ("company_id",  "Store_id" ,  "start_time" ,  "end_time" \
       ,(col("InvoiceData_ROW.TimeStamp").alias("time_stamp"))  \
       ,(col("InvoiceData_ROW.productID").alias("product_id"))  \
       ,(col("InvoiceData_ROW.productName").alias("product_name")) \
       ,(col("InvoiceData_ROW.productSKU").alias("product_SKU")) \
       ,(col("InvoiceData_ROW.productUPC").alias("product_UPC")) \
       ,((from_unixtime("start_time", "yyyy")).alias("year"))  \
       ,((from_unixtime("start_time", "MM")).alias("month")) \
       , ((from_unixtime("start_time", "dd")).alias("day")))

    print ("Unexpexted Error customer_data : ", sys.exc_info()[0])
#       df_customer_invoice.show(1)
    return df_customer_invoice
#       df_customer_invoice.show(1)
def fn_store(customer_data):
### Process to store data
    return df_customer_store

def fn_one_entry(df_customer_invoice):
   df_customer_incoice.createOrReplaceTempView("vw_customer")
   vw_customer.write.mode("append").insertInto("default.customer_invoice_table")
   print ("Unexpexted Error during append QUA : ", sys.exc_info()[0])

def main():
   df_customer_invoice = dict()
   df_customer_store = dict()

   ''' Ready file by file from source_location 1000 files '''

   cmd = 'hdfs dfs -find {} -name *.json'.format('source_location').split()
   files = subprocess.check_output(cmd).strip().split('\n')

   for path in files:
      filename = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split('.json')[0]
      json_file = path
      ''' I believe there is something wrong with this statement as well even though it is loop through will all files, 
      right now it is process all the files, only stop when ether one is missing  'CustomerData' and 'StoreData' from the file ... ''' 

      customer_datafile = spark.read.json(json_file).withColumn('json_file', input_file_name())
      custpmer_data = sensor_datafile.select ( '*'     \
                   , (lit(filename).alias("filename")) \
                 )
       ''' when file contain only 'StoreData' it fails, when it has both 'CustomerData' and 'StoreData', there is no issue ... '''
       customerdata = customer_data.where(col('CustomerData').isNotNull())
       df_customer_invoice = fn_customer(customerdata)
       df_customer_invoice = df_customer_invoice.cache()

       storedata = customer_data.where(col('StoreData').isNotNull())
       df_customer_store = fn_store(storedata)
       df_customer_store = df_customer_store.cache()

       invalid = df.where(col('InvoiceData').isNull() & col('StoreData').isNull())
       print("Invalid Customer data file : " )

    fn_one_entry(df_customer_invoice)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  try:
      main()
  except(KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError):
      print("\nAborting ... Keyboard Interrupt.")
      sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Are you sure that the code is failing because of missing InvoiceData for some entries in the file? Usually if you call `col('InvoiceData_ROW.TimeStamp')` and `InvoiceData` is null for a record (but it's defined in the schema), the result will be simple `null`. Can you update the question with exact error you're getting?

Comment: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`InvoiceData`' given input columns: [CompanyID, EndTime, StartTime, StoreID, StoreData];;
\n'Project ['InvoiceData]\n+- Project [CompanyID#1234, StoreID#7271, EndTime#1679, StoreData#3344, x#1682, y#1683, z#1684, ]\n   
+- Relation[CompanyID#1234,StoreID#7271,EndTime#1679,StoreData#3344,x#1682,y#1683,z#1684] json\n"
18/03/31 09:40:34 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook

Comment: This is file which is failing sample. {"StoreData": [{"x": 1682, "y": 1683, "z": 1684}, {"x": 1712, "y": 1713, "z": 1714}, {"x": 1811, "y": 1812, "z": 1813}], "CompanyID": "1234", "StartTime": 1506985404.0629883, "StoreID": "7271", "EndTime": 1506988575.0722656}

Comment: This is the complete file. .. {"StoreData": [{"x": 1682, "y": 1683, "z": 1684}, {"x": 1712, "y": 1713, "z": 1714}, {"x": 1811, "y": 1812, "z": 1813}],"InvoiceData": [{"productID": "abc", "TimeStamp": 1506728999.2998047, "productName": "product abc", "productSKU": 123456, "productUPC": 12345678},{"productID": "xyz", "TimeStamp": 1506728999.2998047, "productName": "product xyz", "productSKU": 234567, "productUPC": 234567123} "CompanyID": "1234", "StartTime": 1506985404.0629883, "StoreID": "7271", "EndTime": 1506988575.0722656}

Comment: OK, I understand where the problem is now

Comment: hey @SM, did you got a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities to fix your code:

1) For checking if column exists in dataframe don't use `if customer_data.select(col("InvoiceData"))` (it throws AnalysisException), but

```
if 'InvoiceData' in customer_data.columns:
    do_somtehong_with_customer()
elif 'StoreData' in customer_data columns:
    do_something_with_store()
else:
    print("invalid file")
    continue
```

2) It looks like you're processing files one by one, but the schema may change (as some files does not have `InvoiceData` information at all). This is not efficient way of working with multiple files because each processing is starting different spark jobs. I recommend to read all files at once (the schema will be full) and distinguish records basing on nullability of fields, for example:

```
cmd = 'hdfs dfs -find {} -name *.json'.format('source_location').split()
files = subprocess.check_output(cmd).strip().split('\n')
df = spark.read.json(files).withColumn('filename', input_file_name())

customers = df.where(col('InvoiceData').isNotNull())
stores = df.where(col('StoreData').isNotNull())
invalid = df.where(col('InvoiceData').isNull() & col('StoreData').isNull())
```

Comment: Hi Mariusz, Thanks you are big help, this is how my code look like, please see main()

Comment: I am getting following Error message
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference 'filename' is ambiguous, could be: filename#31, filename#46.;"

Comment: I am still getting same message  customerdata = sensor_data.where(col('CustomerData').isNotNull())        
  File "/../../../../pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 1080, in filter
  File "/../../../../py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
  File "/../../../../pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 69, in deco
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve '`CustomerData`' given input columns: 
[CompanyID, StoreData, StartTime, EndTime];;\n'Filter isnotnull('CustomerData)\n+-

Comment: This issue is no longer  Error message pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference 'filename' is ambiguous, could be: filename#31, filename#46.;" ..... Still I am facing the original issue .... Error message pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Reference 'filename' is ambiguous, could be: filename#31, filename#46.;" .... main function is update with current logic

Comment: Did you try running the code without for loop? It's no longer required if you use all files as an input to `spark.read.json`

Comment: No in main() function I have for loop to process all files (let say 1000 files), for out of 1000 files, 9998 files are complete and only 2 files are incomplete meaning they are missing either 'InvoiceData' or 'StoreData' array. My actual code is in main() function.

Comment: I am reading all the json files at source_location in a loop one by one in main() function  .... (let say 1000 files), for out of 1000 files, 9998 files are complete and only 2 files are incomplete meaning they are missing either 'InvoiceData' or 'StoreData' array. My actual code is in main() function

Comment: My updated code is attached in my question main() function is current where code is failing

Comment: If you don't want to switch multi-file processing to give spark control over processing, then you need to use method from point (1) from my answer. I've edited it a bit to show you example flow. But still, I recommend to go to multi-file spark processing, it's much faster and you will get consistent schema.

Comment: Thanks Mariusz for your support.

Comment: When I have such exception like missing column or for any other reason in the JSON file and I do not wants to stop the process the rest of the files, how should I handle such exception? when exception go to next file?

Comment: Yes, but usually you don't process files one by one in spark. When you use method from point (2) from the answer you will not need to stop execution, you will just get this records in separate dataframe for investigation.

Answer (score 0):

```
def hasColumn(df, col):
   try:
       df[col]
       return True
   except AnalysisException:
        return False

def main():
   df_customer_invoice = dict()
   df_customer_store = dict()

   ''' Ready file by file from source_location 1000 files '''
   cmd = 'hdfs dfs -find {} -name *.json'.format('source_location').split()
   files = subprocess.check_output(cmd).strip().split('\n')

   for path in files:
      filename = path.split(os.path.sep)[-1].split('.json')[0]
      json_file = path

      customer_datafile = spark.read.json(json_file).withColumn('json_file', input_file_name())
      customer_data = customer_datafile.select ( '*'     \
                   , (lit(filename).alias("filename")) \
                 )
       if hasColumn(customer_data, "InvoiceData"):
          if customer_data.select(explode(col('InvoiceData'))).count() > 0 :
             df_invoice = fn_customer(customerdata)
             df_customer_invoice = df_customer_invoice.union(df_invoice)

       if hasColumn(customer_data, "StoreData"):
          if customer_data.select(explode(col('StoreData'))).count() > 0 :
             df_store = fn_store(customer_data)
             df_customer_store = df_customer_store.union(df_store)

    fn_one_entry(df_customer_invoice)
```